# What is the term for reverse object destructuring?

Tags: javascript

What is this syntax where you use a variable to create and object literal called?
I'm not seeing it under the docs for object destructuring.
Trying to explain it to another dev and having trouble finding it.

```
const foo = 'bar';
console.log({ foo });

{ foo: 'bar' }
```

Comment: If you read through the [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) there is no **official** given name for that notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "object property value shorthand" or just "object shorthand" and it's just syntactic sugar for object initialization.

References:

- https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/
- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand
- https://babeljs.io/docs/en/learn/#enhanced-object-literals
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015

Answer (score 1):

It is called [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Answer (score 1):

It's been available since ES6 and is typically referred to as "object assignment shorthand" or an "enhanced object literal"